# Why subtract V(BE) in emitter bias configuration?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I have been working for a while on electronic devices.

I am confused as I find everything getting more complicated.

I can easily solve problems but do not understand the basics while writing the KVL equation for these types of circuits.

Why subtract V(BE)?

[image]

Comment: Because the voltage across RB, VBE and the voltage across RE must all add up to VCC.

Comment: What if Vbe was a voltage source, would the formula then make sense to you? Vbe is simply part of the Voltage loop so you have to include it. The way to include it is to treat it as if it is a voltage source.

Comment: Vbe is the forward voltage drop across the base and emitter (like a diode) - do you get that? If so, obviously it must be added (or subtracted) into the loop. Think of the equation as: Vcc = ......

Answer (score 1):

The base - emitter (BE) line of a transistor has some resistance, this results in a voltage drop, as soon, as you have a base current flowing.
Find attached a graph on how the base-emitter voltage usually behaves with a npn-transistor.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Time for another water analogy? These are never perfect but can help.

[image]

*Figure 1. A non-return or check-valve is the hydraulic equivalent of an electrical diode. Source: [LEDnique.com](http://lednique.com).*

If you look at the check-valve of Figure 1, it should be clear that the spring normally keeps the ball in position and prevents back-flow. When "forward-biased" the ball shut-off can be moved against the spring but it will take some initial pressure to move the ball. This results in a pressure drop across the valve: the pressure downstream will be less than the inlet pressure.

In a similar manner the PN junction causes a voltage drop. For silicon it is about 0.7 V. Since there is a PN junction in the base-emitter of your transistor you can expect a 0.7 V drop across it when forward biased.

The \$ V_{be} \$ voltage drop is included in all the other voltage drops in the path highlighted in your question.

Pushing the analogy a little further, we can also see that further pressure drop will occur due to the constriction of the valve. The more water we push through the valve the more the pressure will drop. This will be added to the initial pressure drop required to open the valve in the first place. The resultant pressure drop graph will look remarkably like the *I* vs *V* curve in Krustenkaese's answer.

Comment: Wow, we really understood the question differently. I've never seen the check valve analogy before for a diode. (my teacher stopped using analogies after the going through Resistors, Capacitors and Inductors) This goes into my collection of water analogies to electricity.

Answer (score 0):

Finbarr, Bimpelrekkie and F.Bloggs are all correct in their comments. 
I simply try to sum what has been said in the comments up in an answer form.

First of all. Vcc is applied to the circuit. Vcc is the source of the DC current loop. The resistors have a current \$I\$, multiplied by their resistance, and we get the voltage drop over them. \$I_B\cdot R_B=V_{R_B}\$ (same for the emitter resistor) The sign of this voltage is in the direction of the current, I will simply call this voltage the voltage drop.

\$V_{BE}\$ is the voltage drop of the base-emitter junction. As Krustenkaese posted, the collector current is a function of this voltage. The point though, is that there is a voltage drop.

So by KVL, or simply conservation of energy, the voltages from ground to Vcc has to add up to Vcc. or \$I_B R_B + V_{BE} + I_E R_E = V_{CC}\$. Turn this around, equate to zero and select that Vcc has positive sign and we get \$(+)V_{CC} - (I_B R_B + V_{BE} + I_E R_E) = 0 \$ or $$ (+)V_{CC} - I_B R_B - V_{BE} - I_E R_E = 0 $$